# Magento translations problem, parts of the translation dont take effect

Tags: magento-1.7, theme

I have created and using Magento translations. Translations are placed under app/locale/language_LANGUAGE.csv

After the installation I figured out that some parts of translations dont work. CSV is perfectly fine, I have translated ALL fields that I need, and I have double checked that.

For some fields I had to use inline translations so I searched phtml and php files and edited translations manually. Its a weird thing, because I now have ie some phtml files with 8 fields that are translated from CSV, and one field that is translated manually.

Had someone this problem before? Why does not some parts of translations work?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to add the scope to your csv file? Like `"Mage_Catalog::Special Price:","now:"`

Comment: Yes, It doesnt work neither with that..

Comment: Its pretty weird, I cannot find the reason. 

In example, I tried to translate the sentence "Coupon code is invalid" on the cart review page, and it just wont work..

Answer (score 2):

Magento have multiple translation scopes: Global, admin, theme & module. Depending on which block type (model) each template is defined by, the scope differs.

I'll would try adding your translation strings to your theme at:
`/app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/locale/en_US/translate.csv`

But it's better to know your scope, check which module/class `$this` is an instance of in each template, if it's not already defined in the template top comment block. Then you can add the translation strings to each modules own translation files or create them if they does not already exist.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases "Special Price" is a magento attribute.

You can look it up in the magento admin catalog->attributes->manage attributes.

Look for special price, you can translate it there.